# Not able to connect to mysql from php5.6 while phpmyadmin works well with same user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, php-5.6, amazon-lightsail

Today I have installed a Lighsail AWS instance with OS setup only. I need to run PHP5.6 for my application. I have installed the LAMP stack with PHP5.6. But I guess the mysql version if 5.7.

Now I am able to access the database through phpymyadmin using the same password but I am not able to access it from PHP while trying to connect to DB.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","username", "password");
if(!$conn){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

This line of code returns me `Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I do not understand whats going wrong. If you need more info please refer to [phpinfo screenshot](https://prnt.sc/s73kod) I have shared

https://prnt.sc/s73kod

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: PHP 5.6 has been EOL for over a year. Why are you using it in new installations?

Comment: The application having some dependency of PHP5.6. This is old application. I am converting it to CI but for now I need it to run.